# Phase 10, no card to discard to end the turn

Tags: phase-10

What to do when you don't have a card to discard to end your turn?

(Also, what happens when you lay down a skip card? Does the color change to what the next player lays down or do you have to use the color played before the skip card was played?)

Comment: This should be split up into multiple questions so that they can each be answered in a better manner.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a discard during the game, it means you have played all of your cards, so the round ends. You can end the round either by discarding your final card, or by playing all cards in your hand.

The color doesn't change in Phase 10. Perhaps you are thinking of Uno rules? You can discard any card you like; the color doesn't matter.

Comment: https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/W4729.pdf

Answer (score -2):

In my experience if you don't have a discard, you're out of the game. Some variations allow you to still compete for snaps though.